# Django delete models from db

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have such issue, I created models, than deleted them. I did make migrations and migrate, but when I want to create Group of Users in the Available permissions I see this models and permissions for them.

Models Group, Person, Membership
[image: models Group, Person, Membership]

How to remove them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete also from `auth_permission` table. As you see in the picture there are permissions. You should remove from this table. [image]